# How to force beans in quartz scheduler to be initialized on start up?

Tags: spring, javabeans, quartz-scheduler

```
<bean name="MyJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.package.scheduler.MyJob"/>
        <property name="jobDataAsMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="numArr" value="10,20,30"/>
            </map>
        </property>
</bean>
```

I have a quartz job defined that runs this at 1:30am. The problem is this array definition does not work

```
<entry key="numArr" value="10,20,30"/>
```

We had to use list instead. Since the beans do not get initialized until the quartz job kicks in and it's unlikely we would be coding at 1:30am, we cannot catch this error locally. The only way right now is to change the quartz job's running time to force it to happen. We want to force these beans to be initialized on startup when we are running on local dev. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible I would decouple your bean from the Quartz job. You could then intialise your bean separately in your spring configuration and it does not need to be made aware of Quartz.  I would then use the spring `MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean` to call a method on your decoupled object.

For example something similar to this:

```
<bean id="myBean class="...">
    <property name="numArr" value="10,20,30"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myJob"
      class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
     <property name="targetObject" ref="myBean" />
     <property name="targetMethod" value="doSomething" />
</bean>

<bean id="staleTraderRatesTrigger"
      class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="myJob" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 30 1 * * ?" />
</bean>
```